Chromium browsers cancel HTTP request after 3 seconds and make another one
Related but not duplicate: Chrome cancels URL_REQUEST after exactly 3 seconds
=> this question has been wrongly marked as Resolved. Here, I try to bring new elements to understand what is going on.
TLDR and questions:
Chromium-based browsers are canceling requests taking more than 3 seconds if the URL was written without http(s):// then making another request, resulting in 2 hits server-side. (see detailed logs below)

a) Is there a way to modify this behavior?
In other words, a way to tell Chromium browsers to "wait more" instead of canceling the request and doing another one.

b) How do you handle it? Or maybe a way to avoid it, other than improving performances of the URL, of course :)



Findings and summary:

this issue seems to occur only in Chromium-based browsers (Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, ...)
this issue seems to occur only if you try to access any URL without specifying the scheme http:// or https.
this issue occurs whether the domain has a http->https redirect or not. (see detailed logs below)
this issue has nothing to do with HSTS. I've tested it: with HSTS enabled, Chrome just replaces the 301/302 http->https redirect to a 307 internal redirect request instead)
this issue appears both with HTTP/1 and HTTP2 (tested in 2 different servers)
this issue appears only when the initial request is taking at least 3 seconds.


Detailed logs:

Without HTTP => HTTPS redirection in the global vhost configuration


# Apache logs
[24/May/2024:15:35:54] 1.2.3.4 - www.example.com:443 "GET /testing HTTP/1.1" 200 "www.example.com/testing" bytes:34 time:4042159
[24/May/2024:15:35:57] 1.2.3.4 - www.example.com:80  "GET /testing HTTP/1.1" 200 "www.example.com/testing" bytes:34 time:4027890
[24/May/2024:15:36:01] 1.2.3.4 - www.example.com:80  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 "www.example.com/favicon.ico" bytes:0 time:326

# PHP logs
[2024-05-24 15:35:54.478306] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:35:54.477500] [https://www.example.com/testing] Request received, now I will wait 4 s
[2024-05-24 15:35:57.290657] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:35:57.290000] [http://www.example.com/testing]  Request received, now I will wait 4 s
[2024-05-24 15:35:58.478763] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:35:54.477500] [https://www.example.com/testing] Done, I waited 4 s! It is now 15:35:58.478700
[2024-05-24 15:36:01.291083] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:35:57.290000] [http://www.example.com/testing]  Done, I waited 4 s! It is now 15:36:01.291000

As you can see, the request sent at 15:35:54 is not yet complete, but Chrome is sending another one, resulting in 2 requests server side (that can create issues, duplicates, etc).


With HTTP => HTTPS enabled in the global vhost configuration


# Apache logs
[24/May/2024:15:53:25] 1.2.3.4 - www.example.com:443 "GET /testing HTTP/1.1" 200 "www.example.com/testing" bytes:34 time:4244717
[24/May/2024:15:53:28] 1.2.3.4 - www.example.com:443 "GET /testing HTTP/1.1" 200 "www.example.com/testing" bytes:34 time:4040528
[24/May/2024:15:53:32] 1.2.3.4 - www.example.com:443 "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 "www.example.com/favicon.ico" bytes:0 time:364

# PHP logs
[2024-05-24 15:53:25.953574] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:53:25.948300] [https://www.example.com/testing] Request received, now I will wait 4 s
[2024-05-24 15:53:28.739584] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:53:28.738700] [https://www.example.com/testing] Request received, now I will wait 4 s
[2024-05-24 15:53:29.954046] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:53:25.948300] [https://www.example.com/testing] Done, I waited 4 s! It is now 15:53:29.954000
[2024-05-24 15:53:32.740055] 1.2.3.4 local.INFO: [REQUESTED_AT_15:53:28.738700] [https://www.example.com/testing] Done, I waited 4 s! It is now 15:53:32.739900


Here is a MRE:

Open a Chromium-based browser
Open dev tool on Network tab
paste your "slow" URL, without http:// nor https:// (ex: www.example.net/)
press Enter, and confirm the behavior:

first request sent
then after 3s, the browser cancels it, and requests another one



(It's Laravel code but it's the same with regular vanilla PHP of course)
<?php 
Route::get('/testing', function () {
    $u = url()->full();
    $s = 4;

    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $t = $now->format("H:i:s.u");
    Log::info("[REQUESTED_AT_$t] [$u] Request received, now I will wait $s s");

    sleep($s);

    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $t2 = $now->format("H:i:s.u");
    Log::info("[REQUESTED_AT_$t] [$u] Done, I waited $s s! It is now $t2");

    echo "Page loaded, OK";
});

As described here, you might reproduce this issue without an actual "slow" URL, just by throttling your connection speed.

I haven’t researched this too much, I’ll admit, but I have a hunch this is supposed to be something that improves the UX for the average end user when it’s ambiguous as to whether or not a service supports HTTPS (port 443), defaulting first to HTTPS and assuming the server is improperly configured for it if the response isn’t received within the 3s timeframe. “How do you handle it?” At the risk of stating the obvious… make sure your URLs are well-formed including the desired protocol. Am I missing something?

CANT REPEAT THIS for localhost. NO CHROME VERSION specified, mine works. there will be no issue with DEFAULT PHP CONFIG, that prescribes to abort script execution as soon as the client (browser) drops. this would be a real issue if it wasnt THE ROOT / which is kinda okay to drop after 3 seconds. i would drop it after 1 second if no byte recieved

@esqew yeah exactly what I've reported to my team: "we must have some link without http/https in the wild".. Yeah, it's probably a UX thing from Chromium, but I feed there must be a way to configure server to tell Chrome "just wait more" :/

I think @esqew is probably spot-on here. https://blog.chromium.org/2023/08/towards-https-by-default.html explains the "Automatic upgrades" mechanism in the second paragraph, and says, "Chrome will detect when these upgrades fail (e.g. due to a site providing an invalid certificate or returning a HTTP 404), and will automatically fallback to http://." - that is dated August 16, 2023, so I am guessing they probably added the 3 second timeout in the meantime, due to real-life issues with certain "slow" sites.

'but I feed there must be a way to configure server to tell Chrome "just wait more"' - if Chrome gives up on waiting for a response from the server after three seconds, how should the server be able to tell it to wait even longer?

"we must have some link without http/https in the wild" - not really possible, href="example.com/..." would always be a relative URL, linking into a folder named example.com below the current one. So it would have to be either a link starting with http://, or protocol-relative, starting with //, from a page that was accessed using HTTP only. But the "no protocol" situation can really only arise, if the user typed the domain name into the address bar, I think.
